# pass bundle without replacing the fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle

Is there a way to send a bundle to a `fragment` without actually putting that `fragment` into a container? I ask because I want to take a few `Strings` from an `EditTexts` input field and then call them in another `fragment` at a later time.

I have code like this

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
Fragment fragment = new Assessment_Fragment();
bundle.putString("company", companyName);
bundle.putString("project", projectName);
fragment.setArguments(bundle);

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in, android.R.animator.fade_out)
.replace(R.id.header_fragment_container, fragment).commit();
```

In this code I pass the bundle with the transaction but I also replace the existing `fragment` in the "header_fragment_container". I don't want to do that. I just want to pass the bundled data to the specified `fragment`. When that `fragment` is eventually called I will receive the bundle. Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is this possible?

Sure. Just delete the last Java statement (`getFragmentManager()....`).

Now, as to whether it is sensible for you to create a fragment, then never add it to the fragment manager (either with a UI or not), that's another matter. Java supports lots of classes; `Fragment` is just one of them. If you need a generic data container, choose something lighter weight, such as just the `Bundle` itself.

Comment: Side note, without the `beginTransaction()` statement how is the data passed? with the `fragment.setArguments(bundle)`?

Comment: @i_me_mine: Yes. `setArguments()` is a Java setter method.